# Pyspark: Find N most frequent elements in a list without UDF

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a UDF that users Counter to find the n most frequent elements in a list; the list is being populated using a window function over a certain number of rows preceding the current row:

```
@udf(returnType=ArrayType(IntegerType()))
def most_common(x):
    """Find 2 most common elements"""
    return [y[0] for y in Counter(x).most_common(n=2)]

# Example dataset:
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
   [(1, 2, 9), (2, 3, 1), (3, 4, 1), (4, 5, 2),\
    (1, 5, 6), (2, 3, 2), (5, 89, 12), (2, 6, 85),\
    (1, 5, 6), (2, 12, 2), (5, 9, 12), (2, 65, 85),\
    (1, 2, 9), (2, 3, 1), (3, 4, 1), (4, 5, 2),\
    (1, 3, 53), (2, 13, 1), (3, 40, 1), (3, 5, 1),],\
   ("id", "timestamp", "value"))

from pyspark.sql.window import Window
# example window specification:
w = Window.partitionBy("id")\
          .orderBy(F.col("timestamp"))\
          .rangeBetween(start=-10, end=Window.currentRow)

df_agg = df.select("id", "timestamp", most_common(F.collect_list(F.col("timestamp")).over(w)).alias("top2_hours"),)
```

This UDF works great on the local instance of Spark on Spyder. See the output below:

```
    \+---+---------+--------------------+----------+
    \| id|timestamp|           all_hours|top2_hours|
    \+---+---------+--------------------+----------+
    \|  5|        9|                 [9]|       [9]|
    \|  5|       89|                [89]|      [89]|
    \|  1|        2|              [2, 2]|       [2]|
    \|  1|        2|              [2, 2]|       [2]|
    \|  1|        3|           [2, 2, 3]|    [2, 3]|
    \|  1|        5|     [2, 2, 3, 5, 5]|    [2, 5]|
    \|  1|        5|     [2, 2, 3, 5, 5]|    [2, 5]|
    \|  3|        4|              [4, 4]|       [4]|
    \|  3|        4|              [4, 4]|       [4]|
    \|  3|        5|           [4, 4, 5]|    [4, 5]|
    \|  3|       40|                [40]|      [40]|
    \|  2|        3|           [3, 3, 3]|       [3]|
    \|  2|        3|           [3, 3, 3]|       [3]|
    \|  2|        3|           [3, 3, 3]|       [3]|
    \|  2|        6|        [3, 3, 3, 6]|    [3, 6]|
    \|  2|       12|    [3, 3, 3, 6, 12]|    [3, 6]|
    \|  2|       13|[3, 3, 3, 6, 12, 13]|    [3, 6]|
    \|  2|       65|                [65]|      [65]|
    \|  4|        5|              [5, 5]|       [5]|
    \|  4|        5|              [5, 5]|       [5]|
    \+---+---------+--------------------+----------+
```

But I can't get it to work on the enterprise cluster using Dataiku interface. It returns the following error:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o931.showString.
>   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 4 in stage 20.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 4.3 in stage 20.0 (TID 62874, enchbcclprcp117.srv.bmogc.net, executor 1): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "": error=2, No such file or directory

I'd like to not have to use a udf for this, if possible. Is there a way to find n most frequent elements in a list (that is being populated over a defined temporal window partitioned by the id, like in the code above) natively / without the UDF?

Comment: Hi Tarun, can you provide a sample of the expected output?

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis : Thanks, I have added the expected output to my question. : )

Comment: I consider it to be more straightforward to get an output that includes on the top two rows per in id and timestamp in a flat format. What's the reason for describing the expected output that way? Would getting in this format work for your use case https://pastebin.com/3HAnC2ks?